# Spring XD stream creates only empty .tmp files

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, spring-xd

I'm trying to get Spring-XD working with Hortonworks Sandbox VM.
Everything went smooth until first, test stream:

```
xd:>stream create --name ticktockhdfs --definition "Time | HDFS"
xd:>stream destroy --name ticktockhdfs
xd:>hadoop fs ls /xd/ticktockhdfs
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs          0 2014-04-03 22:05 /xd/ticktockhdfs/ticktockhdfs-0.txt.tmp
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs          0 2014-04-03 22:07 /xd/ticktockhdfs/ticktockhdfs-1.txt.tmp
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs          0 2014-04-03 22:38 /xd/ticktockhdfs/ticktockhdfs-2.txt.tmp
-rw-r--r--   3 user hdfs          0 2014-04-03 22:49 /xd/ticktockhdfs/ticktockhdfs-3.txt.tmp
```

Files remains with .tmp extension and they are empty.

On XD Admin console I can see error:

> could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of 1

**What can be wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in VirtualBox network configuration. I switched from NAT to host only and it's started to working. 
This video can be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xG3nQAfkEyM&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Yes, networking is usually the problem, looks like you could access the namenode but not the datanode. Glad you got it working. I've put together a page on our wiki for running XD against different VMs here - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki/Using-Hadoop-VMs-with-Spring-XD